# Apache aliasing on sublinks of a laravel project - Not working

Tags: php, apache, laravel-5, alias

I have developed one Laravel project and it is working as expected with the artisan command "php artisan serve".

I have another apache server. So I want to run my Laravel application from apache server. 
For that, enabled **mod_rewrite**.
I have created **VirtualHost** and it is working fine. 
I need an aliasing for this. So added the same.

Please see below:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/laravelproject/public" 
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias mysite
<Directory "c:/wamp/www/laravelproject/public">
       Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
       AllowOverride All
       Order allow,deny
        allow from all
</Directory> 
Alias /mysite/ "c:/wamp/www/laravelproject/public/" 
</VirtualHost>
```

.htaccess  content

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /mysite/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Aliasing is working when I call the main link. Example: http://localhost/mysite
But after that any sub link called, it is coming like http://localhost/home instead of http://localhost/mysite/home

Please help me to find out a solution

Comment: If anyone is still looking for an answer for this. `sudo a2enmod rewrite` fixed my problem and I spent hours looking for that. So this might be your solution.

Answer (score 0):

In your .env file check if

```
APP_URL=http://localhost/mysite
```

that's a possible issue

Comment: Still looking for an answer for this problem and as mentioned above it didn't work for me either. I have everything set properly but just the index.php works and not any other router. But when I delete or rename my index.php to something else then I can see the whole folder and I can reach every one of them.

Comment: you have to allow htaccess files in apache